# EAGLContextView renderbufferstorage:fromDrawable: failing frequently on ios8

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios8, eaglcontext

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/opengles/reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EAGLContext/renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:) does not list out the possible reasons for failure. It would be great if I can get any of the following

1. Reasons for failure
2. Replacement for the API using glRenderBufferStorage.

Comment: We're hitting this too. No help. I've tried all types of flag settings for the containing layer, controller and even window. Most people use GLKView which sadly doesn't allow customization, as the EAGLView class.